# Cancel button in showinputdialogbox

Tags: java, swing

I have a few buttons on my panel and everytime I click on it an input dialog box appears. It has an inbuilt cancel button. Now, when i click on the cancel button in the beginning of the code without entering the quantity in the dialog box, it says, "This is an invalid" number. This line has to only appear if the user enters alphabets or symbols, and not on pressing cancel. Can we solve this?

Comment: *"Can we solve this?"* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also note that `showinputdialogbox` is not a method in the J2SE.

Comment: BTW - could either or both of the people who thought "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" explain their reasoning?

Comment: @AndrewThompson robo-reviewers - they won't come back to read you ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra  I don't mind robo-reviewers, they just have to improve the quality of the robo's review skills.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson probably won't - only will be replaced by brand new skill-less examplars once they reach their steward ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First you need a way to decide if a `String` represents a number; the method below uses [`Double.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to decide.

```
private Double valueOf(String s) {
    try {
        return Double.valueOf(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how you might use the method:

```
private void display() {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        null, "Enter a number?", "Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    Double value = valueOf(input);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The value " + input
        + " is " + (value != null ? "valid" : "invalid") + ".");
}
```

See also [*How to Make Dialogs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing,

```
String Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the number?",
    "Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);        
if (Input.equals(""))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is an invalid number");
}
```

The following link explains it even better: [*Simple Data Validation*](http://www-acad.sheridanc.on.ca/~jollymor/prog10082/dataValid.html).

Comment: This only checks for an empty `String`. What about "alphabets or symbols," as the poster asks?

Answer (score 0):

> String Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the number?",
>   "Number", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
>       if
>   (Input.matches(("((-|\+)?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)+"))) {
>       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"valid number");
>    } 
>    else{
>    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is an invalid number"); 
>   }